# Spring pointcut XML expression on custom annotation

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj

I have a custom annotation as follows:

```
@Inherited
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation {
}
```

In Spring XML configuration I have the following:

```
            <aop:pointcut id="fooPointcut" expression="@annotation(com.foo.blah.MyCustomAnnotation)"/>
```

This will only match on method annotations. How do I tweak the spel to also capture type/class annotations?

Answer (score 3):

Use `@within(com.foo.blah.MyCustomAnnotation)` to

> limit matching to join points within types that have the given annotation

A combined pointcut expression would become:

```
@annotation(com.foo.blah.MyCustomAnnotation) || @within(com.foo.blah.MyCustomAnnotation)
```

See [Join Point Matching based on Annotations](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/annotations-pointcuts-and-advice.html) in the [AspectJ 5 Developer's Notebook](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/index.html) for further reference. Also note, that [Spring's AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) doesn't support full AspectJ pointcuts, only a [limited subset](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators).

Also note that `@annotation(com.foo.blah.MyCustomAnnotation)` **in AspectJ** would match

> all join points where the subject of the join point has the given annotation

meaning that it would match *method-execution* **as well as *method-call***. In Spring AOP it only matches *method-execution* though, but it's better to write pointcut expressions that are valid in a broader scope as well, so don't forget to use an `execution(...)` pointcut too to restrict the pointcut.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response - this works perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! Mind accepting and upvoting my answer then? :)